# Does Sony Bravia 2015 Android TV allow extending internal storage with a USB drive?

Tags: android-tv

[According to](https://support.google.com/androidtv/answer/6299083?hl=en-GB) Android TV support, I can expand my internal storage by adding a USB storage device and formatting it using the TV's settings.

> The USB drive can be configured as internal storage or removable storage:
>
> - Internal storage increases the storage capacity of the Android TV. If you choose to set the drive to Internal storage, you won't be able to move data to another Android TV or device.
> - Removable storage lets you move the content on the USB drive to another device. You can store and access digital content. Apps and games won't be installed on removable storage.

The first option is what I want for my new 55W809CBU that I bought recently.  The TV only has 8GB of built in storage, which I think will be decimated pretty quickly if I download some of the supported games.  However, when I insert the USB, I'm presented with an option of opening apps to make use of the storage, but I'm unable to format it accordingly when I visit **Settings -> TV -> Storage & reset**.

I've been unable to find out if this is a limitation of the 2015 Sony TV range or perhaps there's a problem with my USB stick?  I don't really have any other devices to hand to test the compatibility theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your USB. Use ES File Explorer or a PC to crosscheck. I have a Sony W950C model with latest android update installed. It doesn't show up USB drive in **Storage & reset**. May be we can expect this in future updates.You can still view [Sony support page for KDL-55W809C](https://www.sony.co.uk/support/en/content/cnt-dwnl/prd-tvhc/bravia-kdl-w-firmware-update-v2623-eua-UK/KDL-55W809C) to check if you have the latest version of Android.

Comment: Thanks, after scouring those support pages, I think lack of instructions on expanding the internal storage is sufficient evidence that the feature is not supported.  I've got a feeling that the instructions from Google are related to Android M's [adaptable storage](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/05/28/android-m-feature-spotlight-external-storage-can-be-adopted-as-true-internal-storage-or-accessed-normally-with-no-additional-apps/) feature, so I think you might be right about waiting for a future update.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to Sony's advertising, extending internal memory using a USB stick DOES NOT WORK PROPERLY. Not since I upgraded to Android 7. A couple of firmware updates have passed since and this has not been addressed.

Comment: An answer like this which directly conflicts with the manufacturers information should have a verifiable source linked in the answer. Please update your answer with some kind of reliable verification.